# Should an element in a REST API return its own ID?

Tags: rest

What is the benefit of returning the ID of the element? Isn't it already part of the url and therefore known? I am not talking about using the REST API with HAL or something similiar.

```
api/employees/1
{
        "Id" : 1
        "Name" : "Joe Bloggs",
        "Department" : "IT"
}

api/employees/1
{
        "Name" : "Joe Bloggs",
        "Department" : "IT"
}
```

I guess it makes sense to add more information regarding the usage of the API:

The API in question is a public API in a closed network (not internet). We provide sample clients but our customer write their own client for our API. The ID of an element is no sensitive information. The data is not about exmployees (as stated in the question) but about asset management.

The reason I am asking is, that customers are complaining that if they use some kind of middleware (whatever this is), they only receive the content of a element but do not have access to the url of the element (how?).

If you write your own client, is there any kind of situation where you can't get the ID based on the URL? Should we add the ID for people, who somehow do not have access to the url?

Answer (score 0):

What is the client actually using the ID for? Presenting a product ID isn't that wrong IMO but does a user has to know the ID you store the user entity at in the DB when she uses an email to authenticate with the API anyways? So to answer the actual question: it depends. If the client, however, is using it to construct the next URI to invoke I strongly recommend to return links with meaningful relation names instead as this helps to decouple the client from the API as the client does not have to have a-priori knowledge of the API itself.

Depending on the resource it might not be benefitial to have an ascending ID as this might favor guessing attacks and also may lead to strange situation if you remove an item in the middle of the collection. Are the IDs of the subsequent items updated? Is a gap exposed between items? Usually UUIDs or the like are a much safer way to expose such information.

One further aspect to consider is that clients in an ideal REST environment should not interpret URIs itself but use the relation name the URI was returned for instead to determine whether to invoke that URI or not. A client which extracts an ID from an URI most likely has some a-priori knowledge of the API and is thus thighly coupled to that API and will with a certainty break if the API is ever going to be changed.

With that being said, there is the concept of URI patterns which should help a client in extracting things like IDs and names from URIs. Personally I'm not that keen on such things as they promote a misleading approach to the application of REST in an API design.

> If you write your own client, is there any kind of situation where you can't get the ID based on the URL? Should we add the ID for people, who somehow do not have access to the url?

Extracting the ID of an URI requires knowledge of the URI structure. If you ever, at some later time, want to change the URI structure for whatever reason all clients that were built around that knowledge will break. URIs shouldn't contain content as the body is actually there for. As the ID seems to be content for some of the client include it in the response body. You are of course free to add some of the information to the URI though you shouldn't require clients on parsing that URI and extract the required information of it.